# Error message in read_sas (haven package) using cols_only to read in only subset of columns

Tags: r, sas, r-haven

I am using the haven packages' read_sas to import a SAS data set. However, I would like to only include a subset of columns. My data set has 613,124 observations and 189 variables. However, I do not seem to be using the "cols_only" argument correctly. Where is the error in my code?

```
df <- read_sas("~/table1.sas7bdat",cols_only = c("ID","Date"))

Error in read_sas("~/table1.sas7bdat", cols_only = c("ID",  : unused argument (cols_only = c("ID", "Date"))
```

Comment: [Source code](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/haven/versions/1.1.2/source) indicates argument is used. Be sure to use latest version of package. Run `install.packages("haven")` to be sure.

Comment: Thank you. That resolved the issue.